# selenium script run time error

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, runtimeexception

Please look into this error, I am able to run the code and the code is getting executed as well. But this error is occurring at the console.

```
Selenium version- 3.13.0
geckodriver- 0.21.0
jdk- 10.0.1
eclipse- photon
```

[image: img]

Comment: `Unable to read VR Path Registry` that's not what is causing your failure. Paste complete error from console, unable to see from screenshot.

Comment: What is the Firefox version you are using?

Comment: firefox version- 61.0.1